# Akka Http Hello World Performance

Tags: scala, akka-http

With Scala 2.12.2, Akka 2.5.1, Akka Http 10.0.6

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
    implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val route =
      pathSingleSlash {
        get {
          complete {
            "Hello World!"
          }
        }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    val serverBinding = Await.result(bindingFuture, Duration.Inf)
    println(s"Bind complete. Server running and listening at ${serverBinding.localAddress}")
    scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

    Await.result(serverBinding.unbind(), Duration.Inf)
    Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
    print("Exiting.")
  }
```

I use the wrk bencharking tool

```
wrk -t4 -c64 -d60s --latency http://localhost:8080

Running 1m test @ http://localhost:8080
  4 threads and 64 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     6.14ms   29.25ms 826.31ms   96.70%
    Req/Sec    13.86k     4.88k   43.81k    69.37%
  Latency Distribution
     50%  835.00us
     75%    1.24ms
     90%   11.57ms
     99%   87.31ms
  3278911 requests in 1.00m, 484.69MB read
Requests/sec:  54607.92
Transfer/sec:      8.07MB
```

The performance isn't bad but other frameworks and languages do better. Is there any way to improve the Akka Http performance of this simple case?

I see a very similar thread that centers around blocking Thread.sleep operations. I'm focused on the simpler non-blocking use case for the moment.

For comparison, this simple go program:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

is faster:

```
wrk -t4 -c64 -d60s http://localhost:8080 --latency

Running 1m test @ http://localhost:8080
  4 threads and 64 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.04ms    2.12ms 151.99ms   99.92%
    Req/Sec    16.02k     1.32k   19.55k    58.33%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    0.96ms
     75%    1.10ms
     90%    1.16ms
     99%    1.34ms
  3824550 requests in 1.00m, 470.51MB read
Requests/sec:  63740.53
Transfer/sec:      7.84MB
```

These numbers are running on my MacBook. I ran the same test on an AWS `c4.4xlarge` EC2 instance running Debian 8, and all REST tests including akka, Go, and some other combinations ran way, way faster than on my laptop (I hope so). I don't have the numbers handy.

Comment: For starter, you can try with the so-called low-leve api => http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/introduction.html#low-level-http-server-apis

Comment: I tried the low level API. It made no difference in the `wrk` benchmark on this simple test.

Comment: If I was you I would ask on the akka-user Google Group

Comment: How does the value compare to the performance of other frameworks when also running on the same machine? Current performance of akka-http is about 50-80µs of processing time per request on a 3840QM @ 3.3GHz (nominal speed 2.8GHz for that processor). That would be 100k-150k RPS for 4 cores / 8 hyper-threads.

Comment: @jrudolph, I updated the OP with go numbers and, yes, running on a proper server is way faster.

Comment: How long did you warmup for the akka-http case? The Jvm can take 30 seconds or more for full speed.

Comment: I do two sixty second `wrk` benchmarks and keep the second, discard the first.